# How to resume video after a pause call in videoview android

Tags: android, android-videoview

In this example video get stuck on the last frame when it is paused and never starts again.It never goes inside the setOnPreparedListener.

```
 public void pauseVideo(){
            videoPos=videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.w("Video Position", Integer.toString(videoPos));
            isVideoPaused=true;
            videoView.pause();
        }
 public void resumeVideo(){
        Log.w("Video Pos in resume", Integer.toString(videoPos));
        videoView.seekTo(videoPos);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.w("Inside on prepared","finally inside");
                mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.w("Inside on seek complete","finally inside");
                        videoView.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: I want to resume the video from the point where it was paused.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to set `setOnPreparedListener`, Just use below code:

```
videoView.seekTo(video_pos);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: videoView.seekto will not able to go to that exact point instantaneously so I have to start video in call back only

Comment: So you can start video in setOnPreparedListener. videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
      
      @Override
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       
        videoView.start();
      }
     });

Comment: No You have started it in setOnSeekCompleteListener try to call it outside it

Comment: Can you provide more code as i have used same code in one of my application

Comment: Please up vote my question if you think that code is working so that others can use it.

Comment: My code is working and already mentioned is previous comment. What is mp  object in your code and why you are using it??